# Deserialisation to Protobuf object in Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, kafka-python

I have passed a [Protobuf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) object in a [Kafka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Kafka) producer and am receiving a byte array on the consumer side. Now I want to deserialize that response again back to a Protobuf object, but I am unable to do that. How can I do that?

Here is my consumer:

```
from email import message
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json
from simple import simple_message
import check_pb2

consumer = KafkaConsumer('latest', api_version=(0, 10, 1),
                         group_id='my-group', enable_auto_commit=False,
                         bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])#,
           #value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('ascii')))
for message in consumer:
    print(message)
```

I tried to use Confluent but getting

`Kafka Exception : {} KafkaError{code=_VALUE_DESERIALIZATION,val=-159,str="Unknown magic byte. This message was not produced with a Confluent Schema Registry serializer"`

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using Confluent Schema Registry, use [`ParseFromString`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#parsing-and-serialization).

```
for message in consumer:
    value = ParseFromString(message.value)  # example 
    print(value)
```

If (and only if) you **are** using the Schema Registry, then Confluent has a Protobuf deserializer class. See the [example](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/protobuf_consumer.py), which [happens to also use `ParseFromString`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/src/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/protobuf.py#L635) internally.

Comment: tried to use confulent but getting
  Kafka Exception : {} KafkaError{code=_VALUE_DESERIALIZATION,val=-159,str="Unknown magic byte. This message was not produced with a Confluent Schema Registry serializer"

Comment: Your producer would need to use the registry as well.

Comment: my producer is a java service and i do not have control over it

Comment: can you tell me some way to do that

Comment: Do what? That's not required. I was explaining that you cannot use the Python confluent deserializer unless your producer used the Registry... Did you try the code I've already provided?

Comment: my java part has no schema regitry,
can you tell me how can i do that without confluent deserializer ,/

Comment: is there any alternative in python

Comment: Again, I already gave the answer how to deserialize in Python, following the Protobuf documentation saying to use the `ParseFromString` function. That's the only way I know of; there is no alternative.